# Integral of $\frac{x}{x}, \frac{2}{x}, \frac{x}{2}$, and how they relate.

Tags: integration

I'm studying for my diploma of higher studies (i.e. the diploma which gives me access to university) and I have a bit of trouble with building intuiton around integrals.
Derivatives were relatively straight-forward and when in doubt I like that I can prove results with, "fall back on", the definition:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

But so far in my studies I haven't learned any similar equation to define integrals. I've only found rules, such as $\displaystyle 1 \rightarrow x, \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow \ln x$, etc.
I believe this is why I've been getting confused when playing around to better understand them.

Here's the problem:

$$\int \frac{x}{x}dx = \int 1dx = x + C$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln(x) + C$$

$$\int \frac{a}{x}dx = a \ln(x) + C$$ (wolfram alpha)

So why isn't this correct:
$$\int \frac{x}{x}dx = xln(x) + C?$$

I apologise if this is obvious or if my post is confusing. It's probably worthwhile to mention that I study by myself; don't hesitate to recommend textbooks etc.

Thanks!

Comment: The formula for $\int a/x dx$ holds if $a$ is constant. $x$ is not constant.

Comment: Just like there's a product rule for derivatives, there's a product rule for integrals. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: I think for school you can work with first fully reducing the integrand (i.e. here: $x/x=1$). Some integrals of higher difficulty require tricks exactly opposite, but I have not encountered such at school level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well ask, $1/x$ becomes very small as $x$ gets larger, $a/x$ becomes very small as $x$ gets larger, why doesn't $x/x$ become very small as $x$ gets larger? $1/x$ and $a/x$ (for $a$ constant) are very different animals from $x/x$, and it would be surprising if they acted the same way, not if they act different.